# Search query for texarea (with new line....)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with some fields. Address is one of them. I used textarea tag for address.
Now the problem is, when i search something according to one address, it only works for the one line addresses. I mean if i entered a newline (Paragraph format) in my address it doesn't show the result.
All other search query working very well.Here is my codes,

Code for drop-down list of address :

```
<input type="hidden" name="category_address" value="address"/>
<select name='criteria_address' style="width:100px;">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <?php
    $order = "SELECT DISTINCT address FROM lh_clients ORDER BY clientname" or die (mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo ("<option>$data[address]</option>");
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Code of search query :

```
if (isset($_POST['criteria_address']))
{
$category_address = $_POST['category_address'];
$criteria_address = $_POST['criteria_address'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM lh_clients WHERE $category_address = '$criteria_address' ORDER BY clientname";
$result   = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);


while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;"><? echo $data['clientname']; ?></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;"><? echo $data['clienttype']; ?></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;"><? echo nl2br($data['address']); ?></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;"><? echo $data['contacts']; ?></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;"><? echo $data['sensitivity']; ?></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;"><? echo $data['acountmanager']; ?></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;"><? echo $data['responsibleexecutive']; ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

}

I think the search query doesn't work for the newline in addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `LIKE` operator like so:

```
WHERE $category_address LIKE '{$criteria_address}%'
```

This will find all records starting with $criteria address.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. I think the LIKE operator actually looks like this ...$category_address LIKE '%".$criteria_address."%'....

Comment: No, you are getting all results that start with $category_address, so it is $criteria_address%. ($criteria address followed by anything, but preceeded by nothing)

Comment: Here just want to tell that the $category_address is the name of the field in the database. The value of it is constant which is address here. All the time it checks the query matching with criteria_address. which pop-out data from db by <select> tag @Austin
'{$criteria_address}%'
 not working........thanks austin for your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Well...

```
$order = "SELECT DISTINCT address FROM lh_clients ORDER BY clientname" or die (mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($order);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach (explode("\n", $data[address]) as $line) {
        echo ("<option value='".htmlentities($line)."'>{$line}</option>");
    }
}
```

Try use LIKE for search in text columns

```
$address = trim(html_entity_decode($criteria_address));
$query = "SELECT * FROM lh_clients WHERE $category_address like '%{$address}%' or $category_address like '{$address}%' or $category_address like '%{$address}' ORDER BY clientname";
```

Comment: I mention it in the previous comment, that it is not working. Actually i start with this one, after not getting the result use plain search query, by the way thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Tulon do U try search only one line or try search all whole address line with `\n` ?

Comment: whole address definitely with "\n or \r". @Sergey

Comment: @Tulon try search by 'phrase' and use <option value=" with htmlentities for pass value safetly

Comment: @Tulon, and echo $query for execute it in DB query (in phpmyadmin example)

Comment: Ah!.......nope dear it shows an error top of the table
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like '%%' or like '%' or like '%' ORDER BY clientname' at line 1"

Comment: this line was missing "$category_address = $_POST['category_address'];".....so the search text column should be 
"
$category_address = $_POST['category_address'];
$address = trim(html_entity_decode($criteria_address));
$query = "SELECT * FROM lh_clients WHERE $category_address like '%{$address}%' or......
"
But now it shows all rows for selecting any address.